# Android and center text between two images of different size

Tags: android, android-layout, image-processing

Imagine I have a top bar which has a parent-container.

- I want to have text in center of it.
- To the left I have a small-width-image.
- To the right I have a large-width-image.

(Because of the difference in image sizes, I have given each image a parent with the same width. This was to ease text-centering while being able to track e.g. clicks on images correctly. If it had not been necessary to track clicks, I could just have made sure the images were same size with transparency in them.)

I am trying to solve above using the following layout but horizontally viewed, the result is:

- Left-image is not correctly alligned to left within its parent.
- Text is immediately following the left part, not in center.
- Right-image is immediately following the center part.

Thus total failue. Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:id="@+id/myTitleLayout"
  >
<LinearLayout            
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"  
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:gravity="left"
  android:layout_gravity="left"    
>       
<ImageView android:id="@+id/myTitleLogoLeft" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shared__menu__transparent"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
/>                        
</LinearLayout>   
<TextView 
  android:id="@+id/myTitleText" 
  android:text="@string/dotdotdot" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"  
  android:layout_gravity="center"    
/>
<LinearLayout         
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"  
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:gravity="right"
  android:layout_gravity="right"
>       
<ImageView android:id="@+id/myTitleLogoRight" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shared__menu__transparent"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="right"                         
/>                        
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout instead of the LinearLayout. It makes most of layouting much easier.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelateiveLaoyut xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/myTitleLayout">

    <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/myTitleText" 
      android:text="@string/dotdotdot" 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"   
    />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/myTitleLogoLeft" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shared__menu__transparent"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/myTitleText"
    />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/myTitleLogoRight" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shared__menu__transparent"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/myTitleText"                       
    /> 
</RelateiveLaoyut >
```

If the left image needs to be at the left of the bar, add `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` to it. Same for the right image with `layout_android:alignParentRight="true"`.
And also add some margins to the Views, so that they don't stick onto each other.

Comment: I ended up using this combined wih runtime calcluations adjust width of some extra transparent images

Answer (score 1):

check below code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
 android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:id="@+id/myTitleLayout"
  >
<LinearLayout            
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"  
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>       
<ImageView android:id="@+id/myTitleLogoLeft" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shared__menu__transparent"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
/>                        
</LinearLayout>   
<TextView 
  android:id="@+id/myTitleText" 
  android:text="@string/dotdotdot" 
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
/>
<LinearLayout         
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"  
  android:layout_width="100dp"  
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>       
<ImageView android:id="@+id/myTitleLogoRight" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shared__menu__transparent"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="right"                         
/>                        
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thats it and one more suggestion is take click event on LinearLayout instead of Image...

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myTitleLayout"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myTitleLogoLeft"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shared__menu__transparent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="2dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myTitleText"
            android:text="@string/dotdotdot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView android:id="@+id/myTitleLogoRight"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shared__menu__transparent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="2dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This mostly works except the left images (which in this case is smaller in width, but since images are downloaded online I can not know dimensions beforehand) then are centered within the 100dp instead of being aligned to the left